# angular mat-select set default value in form

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

There is a data model with a nested object :

```
export interface Model {
  someField1:string;
  someField2:string;
  someObject: Object;
}

export interface Object {
  someField1: string;
  someField2: string;
  someField3: string;
}
```

there is a form for this model :

```
formBuilder.group({
  someField1: null,
  someField2: null,
  someObject: formBuilder.group({
    someField1: null,
    someField2: null,
    someField3: null
})
```

there is an angular component for this object:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Some Object" formGroupName="someObject">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let object of someObjectes" [value]="object">
        {{ object.someField1 }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I accept a list of objects from the server and let me select one that the user needs. It is necessary that the choice is tied to the form and if the received model already has data about the object, then they should be displayed as a pre-selected item.

Comment: Hi not able to understand what you are trying to do. can you explain with some example

Comment: Hi, my task is dates the user to select an item from the list, then assign this item to the DTO and send it to the server for processing. The problem is that this element can already be specified in the original DTO, and for this case, I want it to be pre-selected in mat-select

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material mat-select offers a `compareWith` API to which you can pass a mapping function to set the default value.

Here is a working Stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-comparewith?embed=1&file=app/select-value-binding-example.ts)